# automated fix for ugly pagebreaks table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking

I have had problems with ugly pagebreaks in my toc. The last section of a chapter had a pagebreak in my toc, so I fixed it with: `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\pagebreak}`

However, I wasn't satisfied with this fix. It worked without problems though, but isn't there an automated command in Latex that is able to fix this problem?

Does anybody know if this fix can be automated?

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11.5pt,twoside, openleft]{book}
\makeatletter
% copied from latex.ltx added \nopagebreak
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
\nopagebreak%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima #3\relax
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {#4}\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hfill
     \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5%
                        \kern-\p@\kern\p@}%
     \par}%
  \fi}

%copy from book but change final highpenalty to nobreak
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil
      \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2%
                                 \kern-\p@\kern\p@}\par
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \nopagebreak%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \endgroup
  \fi}

\makeatother




\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\Large\bfseries}  %BOld fonts for contents
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\Large\bfseries} %Table of contents Chapter style
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\bfseries} %Table of contents section style
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-1cm}
\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{1cm}

\begin{document}
```

Comment: clearly there  can not be a general fix for all possible cases. You could for example prevent page breaks between section level entries and only allow a break before chapter entries, but that fails if you have more than a page listing of sections. You could always force a page break before chapter entries but that looks poor if there are not many sections in a chapter. Often if it is just one line too much you can adjust the spacing and squeeze it on to the page rather tha forcing an earlier page break. It all depends....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How could I prevent page breaks between section level entries and only allow a break before chapter entries?

Comment: define `\l@section`  (and lower) to add a `\par\nopagebreak` before the entry

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How would I define `l@section`? (I'm sorry ,I'm a bit new with this backmatter stuff)

Comment: it depends how your current toc is defined about which you have given no clues

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It is defined in a chapter with 6-7 sections and about 9 chapters

Comment: no I mean each class sets up tables of contents differently so as you have provided no test document can't really suggest how to change unseen code

Comment: possibly enough to add `\nobreak` before the `\vskip` in a copy of `\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am currently using the book document class. Is this a stupid answer?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It does work, however my whole pagestyle including background disappears

Comment: I suggest you fix the code in the question so it does not have the code copied from my answer and then produces a table of contents with a bad page break rather than the error `! LaTeX Error: Command \cftchappagefont undefined.`  Someone may answer with a variant for whatever package you used to define that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would break half way through the toc for chapter 3, without the redefinitions which prevent page breaks before section level headings (it would have been helpful if *you* had provided the test file, it would have saved the comments which clarified that book defintions were being used)

```
\documentclass{book}


\makeatletter
% copied from latex.ltx added \nopagebreak
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
\nopagebreak%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima #3\relax
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {#4}\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hfill
     \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5%
                        \kern-\p@\kern\p@}%
     \par}%
  \fi}

%copy from book but change final highpenalty to nobreak
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil
      \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2%
                                 \kern-\p@\kern\p@}\par
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \nopagebreak%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \endgroup
  \fi}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

{\raggedbottom
\tableofcontents
}

\chapter{zzzz}
\section{Zz}
\subsection{abc}abc
\subsection{abc}abc
\section{Zz}
\subsection{abc}abc
\subsection{abc}abc
\section{Zz}
\subsection{abc}abc
\subsection{abc}abc
\section{Zz}
\subsection{abc}abc
\subsection{abc}abc
\chapter{zzzz}
\section{Zz}
\subsection{abc}abc
\subsection{abc}abc
\section{Zz}
\subsection{abc}abc
\subsection{abc}abc
\section{Zz}
\subsection{abc}abc
\subsection{abc}abc
\section{Zz}
\subsection{abc}abc
\subsection{abc}abc
\chapter{zzzz}
\section{Zz}
\subsection{abc}abc
\subsection{abc}abc
\section{Zz}
\subsection{abc}abc
\subsection{abc}abc
\section{Zz}
\subsection{abc}abc
\subsection{abc}abc
\section{Zz}
\subsection{abc}abc
\subsection{abc}abc
\chapter{zzzz}
\section{Zz}
\subsection{abc}abc
\subsection{abc}abc
\section{Zz}
\subsection{abc}abc
\subsection{abc}abc
\section{Zz}`<
\subsection{abc}abc
\subsection{abc}abc
\section{Zz}
\subsection{abc}abc
\subsection{abc}abc
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, I have only the problem that this fix doesn't work with the `\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-1cm}` enabled. Do you know a fix for this aswell? I have added my code p.s. you're a legend and a lifesaver

Comment: no sorry I warned you that modifying a definition required knowing what the definition was and if you are using some non standard table of contents code then the modifications, that;s why there was a long round of comments before I answerd, Using the standard book class definitions. The code posted now in the question clearly was not working before either, eve without the definition suggested here it just generates the error `! LaTeX Error: Command \cftchappagefont undefined.`

Comment: Well, some things are just too good to be true I guess. I want to thank you for your help and patience! You have helped me A LOT!